# Java Gui Program

Tags: java, swing, layout

This is the first time a make a gui, a math test.  I would like  a code that when a student finished the test, the test shows up again for the next student to answer the exercises. I tried while loop; it just produced 2 gui's on top of each other.  However, I need to display  them  sequentially. I have read Oracle documentation about gui's and I cannot find the answer. This program  has only one exercise, the  real one has 10. I made it short for easy reading. If the parameters of GridLayout look weird, for me it is not important now. thank you.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt. GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MathTest extends JFrame {

    JLabel m,error;
    JTextArea exone;
    JLabel y;
    public JTextField stu;
    GridBagLayout  g;
    FlowLayout  fL;
    Container  c;

    public MathTest() {

        super ("Math Test");

        fL=new FlowLayout();
        c = getContentPane();

        setLayout (fL);

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints g = new GridBagConstraints();
        g.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;

        m = new JLabel("Math Test  10 exercises");

        g.gridx = 0;
        g.gridy = 0;
        add(m, g);

        exone=new JTextArea ( "1. How much is  890 times 500?.");
        g.gridx= 2;
        g.gridy= 0;
        add(exone,g);

        y=new JLabel("Your answer, please.");
        g.gridx =3;
        g.gridy= 0;
        add(y,g);
        stu=new JTextField (4);
        g.gridx=3;
        g.gridy=1;
        add(stu,g);

        Utest manage =new Utest ();
        stu.addActionListener (manage);

    }//end test

    public class Utest implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)

        {
            try
            {
                String text = stu.getText();
                Double num=Double.parseDouble(text);

                if (num==445000)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "   Good start",
                    "Exercise 1 Result ", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE );
                }//end of if

                else
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "    Wroooooong! The answer is 2 ",
                    "Exercise 1 Result  ", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE );

                }// end of else
            }//end of try

            catch (Throwable t)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You must type numbers.",
                "You should follow instructions.  ", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE )
            }
        } //end action
    }//end utest
}//end MathTest
```

Here is the remainder of the code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class University
{
    public static void main (String [] args)  //main method
    {
        MathTest mt= new MathTest(); //Create MathTest object

        mt.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  // Put in JFrame
        mt.setSize(500, 500);    // Size JFrame
        mt.setVisible(true);     // Display

    }//end main
}// end Uni
```

Comment: please format code properly ;)

Comment: Hello Mr. Polywhirl,  thank you for your kind remark. The code is nicely formatted in my editor, but in this stackoverflow looks raggedy. Could you tell me how to do it better?

Comment: i could not see your problem with the current code, please post your full code.

Comment: @MarialaO You can use [prettyprinter.de](http://prettyprinter.de/index.php). It can format PHP, **Java**, C++, C, Perl, JavaScript, and CSS code.

Comment: Mr. Polywhirl, thank you for your suggestion. Next time I will do it. Could you help me with my problem?

Comment: This is for Salah                  import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class University
{
public static void main (String [] args)
{
  MathTest mt= new MathTest();

  mt.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  //250 700
  mt.setSize(500, 500);
  mt.setVisible(true);


}//end main
}// end Uni

Comment: I'm not following your logic at all - I don't see where the loop is to show the test for the next student.  But it seems to me that one way to do this would be to use a dialogue instead of a frame; and create it in a loop from your `main`.  That way, each student would actually see a fresh instance of the dialogue.

Comment: @MarialaO It's hard to read code that's in a comment - may I suggest that you actually do an "edit" to add the code from that last comment to the question itself?  A lot of people will read the question and not bother reading the comments, so they will miss this important piece of the puzzle.